# The Witcher: Enhanced Edition cut scenes do not display properly

Tags: the-witcher

I started playing The Witcher: Enhanced Edition and noticed that, unless I set the lighting settings to low, cut scenes are frozen and won't display.

Is there any known fix to this issue in the form of a mod, or will I need to keep playing with lighting set to low all the way?

Answer (score 1):

- Setting lighting settings to low is actually the best working 'fix'.

Others include

- setting the game's executable compatibility mode to Windows Vista, and
- updating your video card drivers ([Nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) / [AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support)).

These don't seem to work for everyone, however.

---

<sup>sources:

several Steam threads ([1](https://steamcommunity.com/app/20900/discussions/0/528398719787206823/), [2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/20900/discussions/0/828935673069400166/), [3](https://steamcommunity.com/app/20900/discussions/0/846940248978364121/), [4](https://steamcommunity.com/app/20900/discussions/0/620712999977117372/))

on the CD Projekt Red fora there is no mention of a fix ([1](https://forums.cdprojektred.com/index.php?threads/no-sound-or-audio-during-pre-rendered-cutscenes-with-enhance-edition-1-5.13175/), [2](https://forums.cdprojektred.com/index.php?threads/black-screen-during-in-game-cutscenes.12182/))</sup>